# Mac on local network has generic PC icon

Tags: network, file-sharing

I have an iMac and MacMini on my local network. From the Mini the iMac appears as a "mac' icon in the finder window - but the Mini appears as a "generic PC" icon from the iMac. Anyone know why this is and how to fix it ?

I'm starting to get a few weird sharing issues cropping up but thought I'd address this first.

FWIW, I'm running Lion 10.7.4 on both machines and have an airport extreme base station.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may have enabled file sharing with SMB (Server Message Block, default for Windows, which is why the icon looks like a "generic PC") rather than AFP (Apple Filing Protocol) for the Mac mini. Check to make sure by going to System Preferences > Sharing. Choose File Sharing in the list on the left and click the Options button on the right.

SMB is useful for sharing files with Windows/Linux-based computers, but if you only have Macs, stick with AFP. Things like permsissions, hidden files, etc. work much better if you use the native filesharing protocol.

Comment: Yep that did the trick thanks SamE ! Although I was aware that afp is apple protocol and smb windows - and i had afp enabled, I ALSO had SMB checked. Once I unchecked it so afp was the only protocol, all was well again :) That seems like a bug to me but who cares, it's fixed !